# Total War: Warhammer, Dwarf faction victory bug

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I was playing the dwarven faction and got to the point where I achieved the short victory and got the option to end the game. However I wanted to continue and achieve longterm. I have all the conditions yet there is no popup/cutscene or anything. Is this because I need to do a quest? or is this a bug and am I unlucky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check wisely the conditions for long victory, all conditions need to be checked otherwise you didnt't win yet.
If all of this are checked, maybe there are an Orc's horse alive or just your save is bugged.